# How does supersized jQuery plugin generate Image mark up

Tags: javascript, jquery

The other day i was trying to understand how the supersized plugin works, and I was looking forward to using it.

I have downloaded the plugin from the following URL:

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

I was debugging it using Firebug, but I don't understand how the image mark up is generated.  I couldn't find its markup in any of the js, css, or html files...

Can someone please take a look at it, and offer me some direction?

Comment: Seems like markup is generated in lines 68 to 70

Answer (score 0):

The HTML that's placed into the DOM is generated in the javascript file/plugin, the code i've highlighted at https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/blob/master/core/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.js#L67-L76